# C: initstate_r crashing

Tags: c, random, crash, segmentation-fault

I am getting a crash when trying to use initstate_r:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/test.out

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x40052d00 in initstate_r () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

The code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STATELEN    256             /* random number state buffer */

main()
{
 char randomStateBuffer[STATELEN];
 struct random_data randData;

 printf("Before initstate");
   /* seed the random number generator */
    initstate_r (time(NULL), (char *)&randomStateBuffer, STATELEN,
   (struct random_data *)&randData);
 printf("initstate done");

}
```

I have tried compiling this in both gcc 3.3.6 and 4.3.3 and both have the crash.

Answer (score 3):

Try zeroing out randData struct before calling initstate_r().
`memset( &randData, 0, sizeof( random_data ) );`
(Taking a cue from this page: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3662)

Comment: memset( &randData, 0, sizeof( struct random_data ) );

Still crashes.

(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/zeno/test433.out

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x40052c33 in initstate_r () from /lib/libc.so.6

Comment: This was the problem for me, but note that you need to combine this with Joe Valenzuela's note on dropping the adddress-of operator on randomStateBuffer.

Answer (score 2):

This question looks amazingly similar to:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/crash-in-initstate_r-408757/

Also, see:

http://lists.debian.org/debian-glibc/2006/01/msg00037.html

and:

http://lists.debian.org/debian-glibc/2005/08/msg00492.html

The man page for that function is hard to understand, but it seems maybe rand_data should be initialized before passing to initstate_r

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the function signature the second argument is just a char*.  Take the address-of operator off randomStateBuffer.

```
initstate_r (time(NULL), randomStateBuffer, STATELEN,
            (struct random_data *)&randData);
```

?

Comment: +1 And also, don't cast unless you *really have to*; otherwise, it just prevents the compiler from helping you with mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same difficulties and it worked by 0-ing out both state and rand_data, and in your case, removing the & in front of the buffer:

```
char randomStateBuffer[STATELEN];
struct random_data randData;
memset(randomStateBuffer, 0, sizeof(randomStateBuffer));
memset(&randData, 0, sizeof(struct random_data));
initstate_r(time(NULL), randomStateBuffer,sizeof(randomStateBuffer), &randData);
```

worked for me.